rsync: Doesn't seem to be checking size, date/time, or checksum correctly
I feel like rsync is not working correctly for me and I am not sure what I am doing wrong.
Here is the situation.  I have two local directories: /home and /home2.  I am trying to understand rsync, so I am using these local directories before committing across servers.  The /home2 and /home directories were created at some point in the past, but have many of the same files--some newer than others in the two directories.
I have only hidden files in both directories for the user.
## Only hidden files
[root@prod-srvr2 home2] $  ll /home2/newusr
total 0

## List all hidden files in /home2/newusr
[root@prod-srvr2 home2] $  ls -lad /home2/newusr/.*
drwx------.  3 newusr newusr 114 Oct 14 08:23 /home2/newusr/.
drwxr-xr-x. 17 root   root   234 Oct  4 15:20 /home2/newusr/..
-rw-------   1 newusr newusr  87 Oct  3 19:00 /home2/newusr/.bash_history
-rw-r--r--.  1 newusr newusr  18 Mar 30  2022 /home2/newusr/.bash_logout
-rw-r--r--.  1 newusr newusr 141 Mar 30  2022 /home2/newusr/.bash_profile
-rw-r--r--.  1 newusr newusr 376 Mar 30  2022 /home2/newusr/.bashrc
drwx------.  2 newusr newusr  29 Jan 15  2024 /home2/newusr/.ssh
-rw-------   1 newusr newusr 219 Oct 14 08:23 /home2/newusr/.Xauthority

## List all hidden files in /home/newusr
[root@prod-srvr2 home2] $  ls -lad /home/newusr/.*
drwx------  4 newusr newusr 6144 Oct 28 09:56 /home/newusr/.
drwxr-xr-x 18 root   root   6144 Oct  4 15:20 /home/newusr/..
-rw-------  1 newusr newusr   97 Oct 25 19:00 /home/newusr/.bash_history
-rw-r--r--  1 newusr newusr   18 Mar 30  2022 /home/newusr/.bash_logout
-rw-r--r--  1 newusr newusr  141 Mar 30  2022 /home/newusr/.bash_profile
-rw-r--r--  1 newusr newusr  376 Mar 30  2022 /home/newusr/.bashrc
drwx------  3 newusr newusr 6144 Jun  4 20:47 /home/newusr/.dbus
drwx------  2 newusr newusr 6144 Jan 15  2024 /home/newusr/.ssh
-rw-------  1 newusr newusr  290 Oct 28 09:56 /home/newusr/.Xauthority

## rsync with dry run checksum check - ** Incorrect - /home files are newer and bigger
[root@prod-srvr2 home2] $  rsync -Hvnaczh /home2/newusr/ /home/newusr
sending incremental file list
./
.Xauthority
.bash_history

sent 336 bytes  received 26 bytes  724.00 bytes/sec
total size is 1.57K  speedup is 4.35 (DRY RUN)

## rsync dry run size and date/time check - ** Incorrect - /home files are newer and bigger
[root@prod-srvr2 home2] $  rsync -Hvnazh /home2/newusr/ /home/newusr
sending incremental file list
./
.Xauthority
.bash_history

sent 240 bytes  received 26 bytes  532.00 bytes/sec
total size is 1.57K  speedup is 5.91 (DRY RUN)


So obviously I am not understanding what I am doing and what the options mean or some other problem.  Also why are the number of bytes being transferred different on each rsync?
Thanks for any help you can send my way.

files are newer and bigger Uhm...are you having misunderstanding here? rsync does not skip files that are newer (at least not without -u) or bigger on the destination. The idea is mainly to make the destination side in sync with the source side. (And checksum does not tell you which file is bigger, just whether two files are different.)

@Tom Yan - Thank you for your response.  Yes there was a big misunderstanding.  I was under the impression that rsync worked to get the newest/biggest files on the destination.  I totally missed the -u option until after I had sent in my question.  Sorry about that.
